# Tomcat9.0の管理画面にログインできない

Tags: tomcat

PCにTomcat9.0をインストールし、LocalHostから管理画面に
アクセスしようとしているのですが、弾かれて入れません。

下記をtomcat_users.xmlに記述した以外にも、
調べていろいろと設定してみたのですがうまくできません。
どの様に設定すればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？

『32ビット/ 64ビットのWindowsサービスインストーラー 』からPCにダウンロードし、
システム環境変数にJAVA_HOME『C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2』を追加ました。 localhost:8080 には入れますが、管理画面は『401無許可』と表示され入れません。
OS：Win10です。
Tomcatの再起動は、管理ツールのサービスから再起動

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0"> 

<role rolename="manager-gui"/> 

<user username="admin"password="pass" roles="manager-gui"/> 

</tomcat-users>
```

sever.xmlは、下記のようになっています。

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Comment: 詳細な環境の情報（OS、ソフト）、インストールを実施した手順を教えてください。また「弾かれて入れません」とコメントありますが、具体的な記述をお願いします。例えば「404エラーが出ている」とか「ローディングがとまらない」とか「白い画面がでる」等です。

Comment: 『32ビット/ 64ビットのWindowsサービスインストーラー 』からPCにダウンロードし、システム環境変数にJAVA_HOME『C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2』を追加ました。
http://localhost:8080/ には入れますが、管理画面は『401無許可』と表示され入れません。

OS：Win10です。

Comment: 新しい条件や情報はコメントに書くのではなくて質問の[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/70975/edit)を利用して、追記しておきましょう

Comment: 「調べていろいろと設定してみた」のいろいろが気になります。[server.xml](https://qiita.com/aoi28/items/c782113a601231cb6795)でGlobalNamingResourcesの設定およびTomcatの再起動はされましたでしょうか。対応内容を覚えている限りで質問文に追記していただけると別回答を得る機会が増えるかもしれません。

Comment: 管理ツールのサービスから、『Apach Tomcat9.0』を
再起動すると入れました。
半角スペースがダメだったようですね。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password`の前に半角スペースが無いからですね

```xml
<user username="admin"password="pass" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

↓

```xml
<user username="admin" password="pass" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Comment: 半角スペースを入れてみましたが、ダメでした。

Comment: 管理ツールのサービスから、『Apach Tomcat9.0』を 再起動すると入れました。 半角スペースがダメだったようですね。 ありがとうございます。

Comment: @taka 問題が発生したら、まずログを確認しましょう。解決したら[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)して下さい～